# Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have use for loop in my code and but its showing error of Use of unassigned local variable.

Here is my code:

```
public List<CustomTypeLayer.EmployeeLeave> GetLeaveRecord(int emplid)
{
    DataSet ds = objLMSRepository.GetLeaveRecord(emplid);
    List<EmployeeLeave> leavelist = new List<EmployeeLeave>();
    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int k; k < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[k];
            EmployeeLeave leave = new EmployeeLeave();
            leave.DateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dt_from"]);
            leave.DateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dt_to"]);
            leave.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmployeeID"]);
            leave.Reason = Convert.ToString(dr["txt_reason"]);
            leave.LeaveType = (LeaveReason)Enum.Parse(typeof(LeaveReason), dr["id_leave_type"].ToString(), true);
            leavelist.Add(leave);
        }
    }
    return leavelist;
}
```

The error is in the for loop in `k`. You can see in for loop I have initialized `k` with `int k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `k` an initial value, like

```
for (int k = 0; k < someValue; k++)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

No you haven't initialized the k value, you have just declared the variable k as the indexer.

The correct syntax to initialize the indexer of a normal for-loop is the following

```
for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; k++) 
{ 
    ......
}
```

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) references about for-loop

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialised k. You have *declared* it, but not *initialised* it. Change your for loop to:

```
for(int k = 0; k < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; k++)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialization is to actually add an initial value to a variable.
Try adding `int k = 0` in the for loop and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

`k` needs to have an initial value.

It should read:

```
for(int k = 0; k < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize k. Write `k=0` inside the for loop